# Importing some XML to wxRichTextParagraph - wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, serial-communication

I am writing an app that sends formatée messages to ip adresses (at https://github.com/EuropaFantasy/ipms) and in *src/Discussion.cpp* I want to import the XML converted messages (as it can be converted in `DiscussionFrame::Envoyer`), if I send a `wxString` containing the XML instead of the `wxRichTextCtrl` it's value is extracted with `GetValue()`, but it does not keep formatting. I'd like to convert the XML back in `DiscussionFrame::MessageRecu`. I tried the `ImportXML` of `wxRichTextXMLHandler` but I don't understand how to use it.
Thanks for any help !

Comment: Make sure XML is UTF8 or UTF16 formatted.

Comment: Thats not the problem, I wanna convert the XML, I just dont understand the arguments to give to wxrichtextxmlhandler, especially the 1st arg, the wxrichtextbuffer. Thanks for responding !